# i have tried to create microfrontend using this commnad npx create-nx-workspace ng-mfe but getting error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, micro-frontend

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-nx-workspace failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND iaccess.ril.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arghawan.Nawsheen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-26T10_03_55_544Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-nx-workspace@latest' ] failed with code 1

I have tried to resolve thi by using:
pm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/" npm config set proxy http://Sowdjk.eioqepi:5799@iaccess.ril.com:8080
but still  getting error same as previously.

Comment: please do format your erros for a better lisibility

Answer (score 0):

Its looks connectivity problem when trying to connect to the npm registry.

- Check if your proxy settings are set correctly
- `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

or `npm config delete proxy` and `npm config delete https-proxy` to clear the proxy settings,

Hope, you find the solution,